# Is there any way to add a WPF Window with guibuilder support to an existing CLI based VS studio project in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface

I've a CLI application and want to add a GUI to it, however VS only allows me to add usercontrols, but I want to add a window which allow me to edit it by a guibuilder.